# SOBO using OAuth 2.0 Authentication Code Grant?

Tags: docusignapi

Can we use SOBO feature with OAuth 2.0 Authentication Code Grant using REST API?
We cant use JWT authentication due to system limitation, so need to explore if we can use SOBO without using legacy and JWT authentication..

Please advise the flow using REST API!!

Regards,
VG

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer for your question. Thank you!***

Answer (score 1):

SOBO (Send on Behalf Of) is a legacy feature that cannot be used with OAuth 2.0.
JWT (JSON Web Tokens) grant gives you the ability to impersonate, which is essentially the same thing.
IF you cannot use JWT and must use OAuth 2.0 (as DocuSign requires) then you cannot impersonate other users.
May be good to understand your requirements and limitations in more details to try to offer alternative solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response... we are using ERP software which does not have capability to invoke JWT and get the access tokens.... this can only be done via any middleware but at this time client is not willing to invest in middleware...

So we need to stick to oAuth code grant... we are migrating from Legacy authentication!
Appreciate your help and quick response!!

TC

Comment: Your client should talk to their DocuSign account rep

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use jwt (why not?) Then you could have the person you want your app to act on behalf of authenticate with DocuSign via your app using the oauth authorization code grant flow. Include the extended scope to enable ongoing refresh token requests.

This will enable your app to act on behalf of the person, ongoing. (As long as you make an API refresh request once a month or more often.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response... we are using ERP software which does not have capability to invoke JWT and get the access tokens.... 

So we need to stick to oAuth code grant... we are migrating from Legacy authentication!
Appreciate your help and quick response!!

TC